# How to calculate the probability of one 1 customer in 100 making a pruchase, when the published statistic is 1 in 8 make a purchase?

Tags: probability

My college probability is more than a bit fuzzy. I've tried searching, but can't seem to find the right keywords to find what I need.  I also don't know if what i want to do is even possible.

Here's the scenario:

1. I'm an affiliate marketer who has referred 100 new members to a website, and they sign up for a free membership.
2. The website claims that 1 in 8 free memberships convert to a premium membership.  I do understand that i won't necessarily have 12 conversions.
3. I may not trust the website and would like to calculate the probability that out of 100 referrals I get 0 conversions, 1 conversion, 2, conversions, ...

Is this something that can be calculated given the information I have?  Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your point 2, we should assume that the probability that a given customer converts to a premium membership is $\frac{1}{8} = 12.5 \%$. Additionally, we can safely assume that all the decisions made by the customers are independent of each other.

Then, the answer to your question is given by a Bernoulli type formula. Here is the general formula: If you have $n$ customers, the probability that *exactly* k convert is

$$ P(k \ out \ of \ n) = \frac{n!}{k!\cdot(n-k)!} \frac{1}{8}^k \cdot \frac{7}{8}^{n-k}. $$

For example, the probability of having zero purchases of 100 customers is then

$$ P(0 \ out \ of \ 100) = \frac{100!}{0!\cdot(100-0)!} \frac{1}{8}^0 \cdot \frac{7}{8}^{100} = \frac{7}{8}^100 \sim 0.00016 \% . $$

You cna easily calculate other cases with the general formula I gave.

Comment: This implicitly assumes that the people OP referred are representative of the set of all people referred. But this is possibly not so. (I suppose this also assumes that all people who are referred sign up for a free membership, but OP seems to be assuming this)

Comment: I have presented the only case in which you can really calculate the probabilities. Now you could try to take some statistical uncertainties into account - take another value for $p = \frac{1}{8}$ or so, but this is then not so much mathematics, but the question how you think about your customers.

Comment: I am making many assumptions.  The only thing I know for certain is they all responded to the same online ad.  The number of referrals is the actual number that have signed up; I have other data on how many people click an ad and then sign up for fee.

Comment: Thank you, Luke.  That formula does look a bit familiar.  That's just what I was looking for.

Comment: @Luke Yes, I certainly agree. The resulting probability of having $\leq 1$ convert is $\sim 1\,/\,41\,000$, which is really small (roughly the odds of dying from tectonic activity, if you're in the U.S.). It seems likelier that the sample is in some way biased toward nonconversion relative to that of the general population of singers-up---or just that the quoted figure of $1/8$ just isn't true---than that OP is just really unlikely, but like you say, without more information or assumptions this interpretational issue is not a mathematical one.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the binomial method,

> It says,$$$$ let $p$ be the probability that an event will happen,$$$$then let $q $ be it not happening,$$$$if the recordings are done $ n$ times, $$P(\text{Said event will occur r times})=\binom{n}{r} (p)^r(q)^{n-r}$$

Try yourself or click below,

> So probability of conversion ,$$p=\frac{1}{8}$$Probability of non-conversion,$$q=\frac{7}{8}$$For 100 people,$$P(\text{getting n conversions})=\binom{100}{n} (\frac{1}{8})^n(\frac{7}{8})^{100-n}$$$$P(\text{n conversions})=\frac{7^{100-n}\binom{100}{n}}{8^{100}}$$